# Image in math mode causes too-large parentheses

Tags: spacing, graphics, parentheses

My image is correctly cropped, but when I place it between left( and right), LaTeX seems to create a space twice as high as needed and place the image in the upper half. Example (I'm using beamer but this happens in article too with package graphicx):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Hi}{}
  \[ \left( \includegraphics[height=8em]{latex-project-logo} \right) \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

It does not seem to matter what the image dimensions are (e.g. skinny or wide) or what height I request (e.g. 8em or 12pt). Why is this happening, and how can I get the height of the parentheses to match the image?

Comment: the image is sitting on the baseline so has all height and no depth, and \left\right stretching makes delimiters vertically centred on the math axis, so you need to lower the image first either by hand or using an environment such as matrix that is vertically centred by default.

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle said, the baseline needs to be changed. You can use `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` with`\includegraphics[height=8em,valign=M]{imagename}` for this.

Comment: Thanks to both! I more or less understand now what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `pmatrix`

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Hi}{}
   \[ 
     \begin{pmatrix} 
       \includegraphics[height=8em]{latex-project-logo} 
     \end{pmatrix} 
   \]
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]